# Отправка данных JSON в базу данных MySQL Через AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Пример на [CodePen](http://codepen.io/modestfake/pen/WwRqxx?editors=1010).

При нажатии на кнопку Get geolocation data JavaScript добавляет id, широту и долготу в JSON. Вот этот JavaScript код:

```
var JSONID = 0;

// Create a JSON Object Array
var geoLocJSON = new Array();

var x = document.getElementById("location");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

  var myJSON = {
    "id":JSONID,
    "geoLoc":{
        "latitude":position.coords.latitude,
        "longtitute":position.coords.longitude
    }
  };

  // Increments the JSONID
  JSONID++;
  geoLocJSON.push(myJSON);
```

При нажатии кнопки Send geolocation data нужно отправить и записать эти данные в базу данных. Есть PHP файл, который вставляет данные в базу данных:

```
<?php
  //connect to mysql db
  $con = mysql_connect("host_link","login","password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  //connect to the Coordinates database
  mysql_select_db("Coordinates", $con);

  //get the location details
  $id = $data['id'];
  $lat = $data['geoloc']['latitude'];
  $lon = $data['geoloc']['longtitude'];

  //insert into mysql table
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp(id, latitude, longtitude)
  VALUES('$id', '$lat', '$lon')";
  if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
    die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

В JavaScript ошибок нету. Но нужно прописать AJAX запрос, чтобы он отправлял эти данные (ниже пример) в PHP файл

```
var myJSON = {
  "id":JSONID,
  "geoLoc":{
      "latitude":position.coords.latitude,
      "longtitute":position.coords.longitude
  }
};
```

И чтобы PHP файл принимал эти данные.

Я в PHP и AJAX новичок. Но понимаю, что в jQuery, можно использовать данный метод:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url_to_php_file,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Но как этой конструкции сказать, чтобы она брала именно данные из geoLocJSON массива (а именно данные объекта myJSON) и как потом в PHP прописать, чтобы он эти данные принял?

Comment: вы хотите за 1 раз отправить данные? или вы хотите каждый массив по отдельности отправлять на сервер?

Comment: Пользователь определит своем место расположения, создастся объект с данными. И дальше нужно отправить эти данные. То есть, по сути, будет существовать лишь один объект, поэтому и отправка будет один раз. Но нужно всё это сделать без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас есть массив объектов `geoLocJSON`. Зачем он является массивом - не понятно. Тем не менее будет брать из него последний элемент:

```
var requestData = getLocJSON[getLocJSON.length - 1];
```

Это будет объект с ключами `id` и `geoLoc`.
Его необходимо передать в формируемый ajax запрос.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url_to_php_file,
  data: requestData, // <- geo object
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Далее, я считаю, что наилучшим способом передачи будет, если отправлять с заголовком `Content-type: application/json`:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url_to_php_file,
  data: JSON.stringify(requestData), // <- update
  contentType: 'application/json', // <- json
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

На сервере же вам необходимо будет принять запрос:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

На выходе будет php object, и к свойствам объекта необходимо обращаться так `$data->id`, `$data->geoLoc`.

`var_dump($any_argument)` вам поможет отлаживать на сервере.

Comment: php-файл работает, в таблицу записываются данные, но пишет туда 0, 0. Испоьзовал вашу строку
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
И для вывода информации var_dump($data);
Пишет NULL. То есть, php-файл не получил объект.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  var requestData = geoLocJSON[geoLocJSON.length - 1];

  $("#send-gl-data").on("click", function() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../myphp.php",
      data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
  });
});
 `
Этот код в консоли выдает ошибку ReferenceError: success is not defined. Меняю на:
`success: function() {
console.log("Success");
}`
И тогда получаю аналогичную ошибку для dataType

Comment: потому, что у вас dataType переменная не определена, да и вообще зачем вам определять dataType?

Comment: Убрал dataType и в саксес прописал `success: function() { console.log("Success"); }`
Ошибки уже нету, всё хорошо. Но `var_dump($data);` Всё равно выдает NULL

Comment: var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')) ?

Comment: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`
`var_dump($data);`

Comment: результат `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` выведите

Comment: В этом случае показывает не NULL, а string(0) ""

Comment: а `console.log(JSON.stringify(requestData))` на фронтенде перед отправкой что выводит?

Comment: И до и после отправки выдает ReferenceError: requestData is not defined. Хотя переменная requestData определена

Comment: В вашем листинге кода не понятно где происходит вызов функции `showPosition`, по этому я не могу понять, что происходит до вызова `$.ajax`. Обновите листинг

Comment: Всё, я разобрался. Чуть поправил переменные и заработало. Извините, что напрягал. Вы очень помогли! Спасибо!